# Tempus Dominus date picker, format not working if date null

Tags: tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm using Tempus Dominus datetime picker in a Bootstrap 4 / ASP.net MVC Core 2 website.

I want to only display date in Euro format - it works when the date is populated from the database when editing a record. But when it is null in the database it ignores the format and displays using US format with time present when the user selects a date.

I use this script in the page to set the format

```js
$(function () {
    $('.date').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'en-gb',
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    });
})
```

How can I get this format working when the date is null? I can only find things on Google that set the date in the above way, i can't see any issues about this not working if date is null.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a solution as well. I found [this](https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/issues/113) on github. Tell us if you manage to do anything

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what fixed it, but try making the date nullable.

Answer (score 1):

this Fix from github , it error from function _getLastPickedDate() in file tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js

step to fix

1.unmin file tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js

2.find _getLastPickedDate()

3.replace with `var lastDate = this._dates[this._getLastPickedDateIndex()]; if (typeof lastDate == "undefined" || lastDate == null) { lastDate = this.getMoment(); } return lastDate;`
cr. github

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I always test the values of my datepickers. I suggest you to initialize the value of your datepicker with the value in the input. If the value is null nothing is render

```js
$('.datepicker').each(function () {
    const val = $(this).val();
    const format = 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    alert(val);
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        format: format,
        userCurrent: false,
        date: moment(val, format)
    });
});
```